# Rebuild Solution Vs Rebuild "ProjectName"

Tags: visual-studio

I've always wondered, what is the actual difference between building / rebuilding / cleaning the solution vs the set of these options with your specifcic project name vs the set that says 'only "projectName".?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuild project will rebuild a project and all projects it depends on. Rebuild solution will rebuild *all* projects in the solution that are enabled for the current configuration.

For a small solution the result is probably the same, for larger solutions the difference can be quite significant.